# Swap arrays in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have created a method that inherits from Array class to swap two arrays:

```
class Array
  def exchange_with!(other_array)
    self,other_array=other_array,self
  end
end
```

But i get error `Can't change the value of self (SyntaxError)`.
I have also tried:

```
class Array
  def exchange_with!(other_array)
    self.replace(other_array)
    other_array.replace(self)
  end
end
```

But it returns value of last swaped array:

```
a=[1,2,4]
b=[5,6,7]
a.exchange_with!(b)
a #> [5, 6, 7]
b #> [5, 6, 7]
```

what i need is `a #> [5, 6, 7]` and `b #>[1, 2, 4]`

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are trying to do. Do you want to swap the identities of the two arrays (akin to [tag:smalltalk]'s `become:`) or the contents?

Comment: am swapping whole array,am assuming their sizes are equal..

Comment: Yes, but do you want to swap the contents or the identities?

Comment: am swapping identities

Comment: Any idea why you can't alter self in ruby?

Comment: Another queston is if it is a good idea at all. What problem do you want to solve? maybe there are better solutions.

Comment: You can't swap the identities of objects in Ruby. There are a couple of languages where it is possible: [tag:smalltalk], [tag:selflanguage], [tag:newspeak], and [tag:ioke], for example.

Comment: @Jörg, you seem to collect languages like some people collect baseball cards or Barbie dolls.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: the programming language is the developer's most important tool. How do you know which tool to use for a given problem if you don't know what tools you have?

Comment: @Jörg, you have misunderstood my comment. I find the breadth of your knowledge more than impressive.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: No no, I understood you perfectly! This was not a defensive statement, but a motivating one (*my* motivation to be precise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below:

```
class Array
  def exchange_with!(other_array)
    other = self.dup
    self.replace(other_array)
    other_array.replace(other)
  end
end
```

You cannot assign new values to `self`, but you can always modify the contents of `self` by using methods available on that class.

Here we can use `Array#replace` to replace the contents of an array with another ary.

To better understand, how variables are passed to methods in Ruby, have a look at [this article](http://robertheaton.com/2014/07/22/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value/).

Comment: This is a nice solution for swapping the contents. It's not quite clear from the question whether the OP wants to swap the contents or the identities. If the latter, the answer is simple: you can't, use [tag:smalltalk] instead.

Comment: can one use self.clone instead of self.dup ?

Comment: @cary I found out clone is bit slower than dup but not that significant.

Comment: @owade, my reference to [AWOL](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=AWOL) was meant for Wand, who has not been to SO much in recent days. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland  Yeah - I been on and off lately.